# Android - Image processing library for simple resize/create operations with highres images

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I am looking for a way to realize the following operations on Android:

- simple resize to high resolutions
- simple crop with high resolution output

With high resolution i mean things like 8MP and above. It's clear that those images cannot be loaded into memory because of the low memory. But are there libraries available that do these kind of things in a more memory friendly way (like doing it tile based or something this)?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not avare of libraries working this way,  but you can overcome memory allocation problems
by using mmapped bufers -  they are outside of heap and just plain buffers.  You shoild be able to use whatever  library you like provided it will work with byte buffers provided by you

Comment: i have found the java class "MappedByteBuffer" which is what you are talking about, i think ;) But i haven't found any way to use it in combination with Android's BitmapFactory :( But you are right, it will do the job with other libraries. Thanks

Comment: You can create bitmap over int[]  array:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29  I do thin JavaOCR android demos: http://sf.net/projects/javaocr

Comment: @Goddchen...Did you get the solution??